# Keeping home and office separated

Tags: networking

I currently have 2 ISPs and one gateway from each company.  I would really like to eliminate one ISP to lower costs but I need to have completely separate networks fro work and home. I use a Mac desktop and Mac laptop for work but at some point I may add a Windows pc.
What is the easiest way to do this? I am not a very technical person.
Once that is done, I want to ensure that the work network is as secure as it can be because I sometimes deal with sensitive information.

Comment: Look up how to set up a VLAN. I'm not knowledgeable enough to tell you how, especially given I don't know what router and switch you use, but this is what you have to do.

Comment: You can daisy chain another router from the first router, configure it to have a different ip. example, first router is probably 192.168.1.1, make the second router 192.168.10.1, this is configured in the router firmware.

Comment: VLAN is pretty complicated but it’s probably the best solution.  If I set up another router, is that creating a subnet or is that something else,entirely?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly you do this depends on your goals and criteri. It envolves playing with routers. In the end, if its connected to the Internet its all part of 1 network, so what you are probably referring to is having systems on different LANS - ie what systems can communicate directly with each other.

The easiest and most comprehensive way to do this is with 3 routers - Connect 2 routers (WAN ports) to your ISP router LAN ports. designate one for home and one for work. The only thing is you probably need to change the IP range of the LAN (eg from 192.168.1.1 to say 10.110.1 and 10.1.2.1.1 on each of the 2 additional routers, assuming all routers come with the typical default of 192.168.1.1). Connect work clients to 1 router and home clients to the other. The only things that should be connected to the ISP router are the 2 client routers and upstream connection. Its a good idea yo disable WIFI.

Alternatively you could do something similar using only 1 additional router, in which case you would plug your home devices into the ISP router, and your work devices into the second router. Provided the routers are using typical NAT configuration between LAN and WAN, the work network should be isolated from the home network (although the home network would still be reachable from the work one) - this configuration protects work routers from home, but not so much the opposite.

A third option would be to use dd-wrt and configure 2 networks from 1 router. This is fairly technical to fully isolate though, and probably not worth the time compared with the 3 router solution. This would relate to the VLAN solution others have commented on.

Another consideration is to set up a VPN between your home and work. This protects different aspects of your connection, and IMHO is way more important then isolating subnets, as, correctly set up, it protects against interception of data between you and your work. Your work will need to set up a VPN server to facilitate this.   (FWIW, I work on the fringe of the financial services industry and I enforce VPN for access to the main offices - and dont worry excessively about what is on peoples LANs.)